# Making html elements in separate divs accessible by arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following layout in my webpage. When my page loads, the focus by default is set on the folder 1. Thereon, user should be able to use all arrow keys to navigate within the folder and image items. 
Folders are in one  and images are in another . I handled the keydown events for arrow keys to set focus on different items in this grid. Right arrow takes to folder 2, 3, 4 and respectively. From folder 2, down arrow takes to folder 5 and then up arrow brings back to folder 2.

Things get tricky when I want to jump divs while setting focus. From folder 5, down arrow should take user to Image2 and right arrow should take him to Image1. From Image3, up arrow should take him to Folder5 and down arrow should take him to Image5.

All this can be achieved with java-script handling of all keydown events and creating a grid of array elements and handling the part of div-jump inbetween as a special case.

But I feel there must be a simpler way of doing this that I don't know about. (Newbie in web development). Any suggestions?

[image]

PS: I am not looking for readymade code here. Just want to know what are the possible approaches. Any direction you can point me in?

Comment: Could you maybe add some of your code here, or create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show us what you have done and tried?

Comment: Can't you use `tabindex`?

Comment: tabindex is useful for setting tab order. Once tab brings the focus to first element, i want user to be able to navigate using arrow keys.

Comment: you are on the right path, handle keydown events on the parent div( parent of both folders and images) and internally you can have a matrix for position resolution, i doubt there is any better way than that